# Criando um positiveButton em um Dialog no Android

Tags: android, android-activity

Tenho o seguinte método para criar um `Dialog` em uma aplicação Android:

```
public static void alertBuilder(String mensagem, Type tipo, Context contexto){

    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(contexto, R.style.alert);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.alert_box);

    TextView text = dialog.getWindow().findViewById(R.id.mensagem);
    TextView type = dialog.getWindow().findViewById(R.id.alerta);
    ImageView image = dialog.getWindow().findViewById(R.id.imagem);

    switch (tipo) {
        case SUCCESS:
            image.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath("@drawable/ic_ok"));
            type.setText("Pronto!");
            text.setText(mensagem);
            break;
        case ERROR:
            type.setText("Atenção!");
            text.setText(mensagem);
            break;
    }
    dialog.show();
}
```

E queria adicionar um botão de "ok" que fechasse o `Dialog` quando fosse clicado, mas não existe um método de `setPositiveButton` na classe `Dialog` como na classe `AlertDialog`.

Não posso fazer a conversão de uma classe pra outra, pois como se vê aí nesse trecho de código, eu tenho um `layout` universal para o `Dialog` do meu aplicativo, que modifica a mensagem do `layout` dependendo do tipo de evento.

Alguma sugestão de como adicionar esse botão?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> E queria adicionar um botão de "ok" que fechasse o Dialog quando fosse clicado. [...]
>   Alguma sugestão de como adicionar esse botão?

### 1. Criar um Botão no layout do diálogo

Você pode adicionar um `Button` ao fundo do seu próprio `alert_box.xml`, digamos:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@android:string/ok"
    android:id="@+id/dialog_box_botao_ok"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"/>
```

E então fazê-lo dispensar o diálogo ao ser clicado:

```
Button b = dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_box_botao_ok);
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});
```

### 2. Usar um AlertDialog

```
public static void alertBuilder(String mensagem, Type tipo, Context contexto) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(contexto);
    // Aí está
    View dialogView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.alert_box, null);

    TextView text = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.mensagem);
    TextView type = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.alerta);
    ImageView image = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.imagem);

    //builder.setTitle(android.R.string.dialog_alert_title);
    //builder.setMessage(mensagem);
    builder.setView(dialogView);

    switch (tipo) {
        case SUCCESS:
            image.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath("@drawable/ic_ok"));
            type.setText("Pronto!");
            text.setText(mensagem);
            break;
        case ERROR:
            type.setText("Atenção!");
            text.setText(mensagem);
            break;
    }

    builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
```